# Why there is no d'Alembert solution in 2D?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

In 1D the wave equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}$$
can be satisfied with a wave
$$u(r,t) = f(r-ct).$$

In 3D the wave equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\biggl(r^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\biggr)$$
can be satisfied with a wave
$$u(r,t) = \frac{1}{r}\,f(r-ct)$$
whose amplitude fades to comply with conservation of energy.

One might expect that in 2D the wave equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\biggl(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\biggr)$$
could be satisfied with a wave
$$u(r,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt r}\,f(r-ct),$$
but that's not the case. What is the reason for it?

Comment: Shouldn't those wave equations be ${\partial\over\partial r}\left(r^k{\partial u\over\partial r}\right)$? (i.e., no $u$ in the outer partial.)

Comment: Well, we know the *actual* solution. In 2D, this solution shows that if you have a compactly supported initial condition, then you do *not* see a disturbance at a given point for only a finite period of time. Instead you see a disturbance at a given point forever, with decaying amplitude. Evans proves this using the method of descent (solve the problem in 3 dimensions, then treat the 2 dimensional problem as a 2 dimensional problem with no dependence on $x_3$, then write the integrals in a more natural 2D form).

Comment: Typo: "treat the 2 dimensional problem as a *three* dimensional problem with no dependence on $x_3$, ..."

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what happends if we consider the $n$-dimensional wave equation for radial functions,
$$
\newcommand{\pl}{\partial}
\pl_t^2 u = c^2 r^{-(n-1)} \pl_r ( r^{n-1} \pl_r u)
$$
and try an ansatz of the form
$$
u(r,t) = r^{s} f(r-ct).
$$
By direct computation, we find that
\begin{align}
\pl_t^2 u & = c^2 r^s f''(r-ct), \\
c^2 r^{-(n-1)} \pl_r ( r^{n-1} \pl_r u) 
& = c^2 r^s ( f''(r-ct) \\
& \phantom{=} + (n-1+2s) f'(r-ct) r^{-1} + s(n-2+s) f(r-ct) r^{-2} ).
\end{align}
These two match identically if
$$
\begin{cases}
n-1+2s = 0 ,\\
s(n-2+s) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
There are two cases.

1. Take $s = 0$, then $n = 1$.
2. Take $n-2+s = 0$, then $s = -1$ and $n = 3$.

These are exactly the two cases mentioned in your question. As you see, there are no other dimensions in which such an ansatz works. Of course, it's nice to have a more conceptual explanation than just arithmetic coincidence; for this, see the comments.